# C++ i don´t want a comma after the last value

Tags: c++

My program is supposed to find the factors of numbers and print them out with a comma between them. Except the last one. No comma there.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int number;
    cin >> number;

    if (number < 1)
    {
        cout << 0;
    }
    else if (number == 1)
    {
        cout << number;
    }

    for (int i=2; i <= number; i++)
    {

         while (number % i == 0)
         {
             number /= i;
             cout << i << ", ";
         }

    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Let's work through it... How do you know when you have reached the last value? What can you do to only output a comma when it is not the last value?

Comment: Put the comma before the number except for first number

Comment: Shame on the upvoter! xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
for (int i=2; i <= number; i++)
{

     while (number % i == 0)
     {
         number /= i;
         cout << i << (number != 1 ? ", " : "");
     }

}
```

Comment: Hahahaha. More cryptic please :D. But back to the point: Do you think he will understand what the case check part is beahving like, after he can't review even his own easy code?^^ You should alsoe xplain it.

Comment: Works in this case, not a general solution to the problem

Answer (score 0):

The simpler solutions:

```
std::string sep;

for( int i = 2; i <= number; ++i )
{
    while( number % i == 0 )
    {
       std::cout << sep << i;
       sep = ", ";

       number = i;
    }
}
```

No need for `if` in the loop but in the first iteration `sep` is an empty string

With a bool the simplest approach is:

```
bool first = true;

for( int i = 2; i <= number; ++i )
{
    while( number % i == 0 )
    {
       if( !first )
           std::cout << ", ";
       else
           first = false;

       std::cout << i;

       number /= i;
    }
}
```

Take your pick. There's something nice about the first except it keeps resetting sep to the same value every iteration of the loop. You could put `if( sep.empty() )` before it.